# Move large volumes (> 50tb) of data from one s3 to another s3 in another account cost effectively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, migration, file-transfer, data-transfer

I have some S3 buckets in one AWS account which have large amount of data (50+ Tbs)

I want it to move it to new S3 buckets in another account completely and use the 1st AWS account for another purpose.

The method I know is AWS CLI using s3 cp/s3 sync/s3 mv , but this would take days when running in my laptop
And I want it to be more cost effective when considering the data transfer also.

Buckets contain mainly zip files and rar files having size ranging from 1GB to 150+GB and also other files too.

**Can someone suggest me methods to do this which would be cost effective as well as less time consuming .**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) which is much faster and cheaper than `aws s3 cp` (up to 110x for large files). Skyplane will automatically compress data to reduce egress costs, and will also give you cost estimates before running the transfer.

You can transfer data between buckets in region A and region B with:

```
skyplane cp -r s3://<region-A-bucket>/ s3://<region-B-bucket>/
```

Answer (score 1):

If the destination bucket is in the same region as the source bucket (even if it's in a different account), there's no data transfer cost for running `s3 cp/sync/mv` according to [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) (check the `Data transfer` tab).

For a fast solution, consider using [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration.html), but note that this does incur transfer costs.

Comment: But this method would cost a lot of time because i have a data of more than 50 Tb, i s there way to reduce time

Comment: You can try making multiple calls to `s3 cp` for multiple prefixes or objects in parallel. You can technically have up to 3,500 PUTs per second into the destination bucket.

Comment: Is there any other method like s3 batch replication, which we can implement???